# 404 When running .Net application when using IISExpress

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404

Like the title says I'm getting a 404 when trying to start my .net app with IIS Express in Visual Studio. I'm thinking it has to have something to do with my routing, but I can't figure out why. It never gets to my controller and this happens immediately after it setups up my claimstransformer.

Here is my Startup:

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => {
            //kpd debug toggled to true
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy(CONSTANTS.EDIT_POLICY_NM, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new SameAuthorRequirement()));

         ... More Authorizations ...

        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentRepository, MyRepository>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(CONSTANTS.ERROR_REDIRECT_URL);
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

         *** This is where it goes into immediately after my claimstransformer setup with 404 ***
        app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(CONSTANTS.STATUS_CODE_MSG + response.StatusCode
                + " for user:  " + context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            //Home
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default", 
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            ... More Routes ...
        });
    }
}
```

My IIS Express settings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44375/",
      "sslPort": 44375
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44375/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "use64Bit": true
    }
  }
}
```

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <appSettings>
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44375" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many reasons for 404 error, can you post more information about about it?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to get more info?  I've tried a lot, I don't have any other relevant info.

Comment: You can check the Event viewer, or try to debug your project.